# FancyBox open on click (from complete newbie)

Tags: fancybox

Hi there and thanks in advance. I have this code (BTW I'm just a sys guy who was asked to do this)

We have a website that has two maps on it now they open on mouseover which is very very irritating and we want to turn the open on mouseover off. I haven't the vaguest idea I'm afraid I tried looking at the fancy box site but nothing I can see helps. Pretty much it's all gobledygook to me I'm afraid.

This is the code that it uses

```
/* <script>
$(".test").fancybox({
    href: "http://localhost/img/map.jpg"
});

$(".test").hover(function() {
    $(this).click();
    $("#fancybox-overlay").remove(); //remove the overlay so you can close when hover off.
}, function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
});</script> 
*/ ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#single_image").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this part of the script:

```
$(".test").hover(function() {
    $(this).click();
    $("#fancybox-overlay").remove(); //remove the overlay so you can close when hover off.
}, function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```

then you could change this line

```
$(".test").fancybox({
    href: "http://localhost/img/map.jpg"
});
```

in something like

```
$(".test").fancybox();
```

because you may need to open the maps on click, just make sure you have in your html code something like:

```
<a class="test" href="http://localhost/img/map.jpg">open map 1</a>
<a class="test" href="http://localhost/img/map02.jpg">open map 2</a>
```

Comment: righto I've ha dthe btter part of a bottle of wine will try this tomorrow :-)

Comment: send me one, from Bordeaux preferably (Pauillac or Pomerol)